# Is it possible to run sidecar with a different service account

Tags: kubernetes

I want to run 2 containers in a pod (sidecar pattern), Of which one of the container must be running with restricted access. In K8s service account is common for all containers in the pod, is it possible to run a sidecar with a different service account or with no service account?

Comment: Did offered solution help you?

Answer (score 3):

I just asked the same question for init container in the slack group. The answer was a no.

Although, one user had the idea of manually mounting a SA token into the initcontainer or sidecar in your case and disabling automounting of SA.

Comment: If I use a deamonset with a different serviceaccount will it inject a container with different service accout?

Comment: That's an interesting idea! any example on disabling automounting SA with initContainer having SA access?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. I never did something like this, and even the user coming up with the idea noted that he never tried to do it. It was just a spontaneous idea. I am not sure about the deamonset either.  Maybe come to slack and join the discussion https://kubernetes.slack.com/archives/C09NXKJKA/p1636659074252400